# Change property of CSS class in GWT at runtime

Tags: css, gwt

I'm familiar with assigning CSS classes to GWT elements to control their formatting, but what if I want to change an attribute in one of those CSS classes?

I've got a styled list of data.  CSS classes are used to indicate the various data types  (important, routine, trivial).  I wish to allow the user to hide trivial entries.  I'd like to modify the `span.trivial` CSS class to set `display:none`

I'm aware I could loop through the entries, see if an entry is `trivial` and add a `noShow` class (which itself has `display:none`) - but then I'm doing the looping, I'd rather let the browser do the work.

Is this possible in GWT?

Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume we have a structure similar to the following one

```
<div>
    <span class="routine">A</span>
    <span class="trivial">B</span>
    <span class="trivial">C</span>
<div>
```

This is how I would solve the problem:

```
.hideTrivial span.trivial {
    display: none;
}

<div class="hideTrivial">
    <span class="routine">A</span>
    <span class="trivial">B</span>
    <span class="trivial">C</span>
<div>
```

The `".hideTrivial span.trivial"` selector applies only to "trivial" spans, if they occur within another element that has the class "hideTrivial". (Note: The span doesn't have to be a *direct* child of the "hideTrivial" div - it's ok, if you have a deeper element hierarchy.)

So to turn on/off hiding, you simply add/remove the "hideTrivial" class from the outer div.

(This technique can be used with and without GWT.)

Comment: cha-ching! perfect answer.  I Was focussing on GWT here in 2011, and forgetting html in 1995!  Great solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, javascript can not change the CSS file and have it reapplied. The same goes for GWT (since it compiles down to JS). So, you can not change a CSS rule and have all elements in your DOM reflect the change.

However, you can get a style of a DOM element and change that style. But that is for a particular element. In your case you'd still need to write code to traverses a set of element and make the change.

My suggestion would be to look at [gwtQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/GettingStarted) (a port, not a wrapper, of jQuery to GWT). It's super-efficient and super-compact. Here is a one-liner to do what you need:

```
$("span.trivial").hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

Fot those who need to modify global CSS property values: you can choose StyleInjector for that purpose.
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/dom/client/StyleInjector.html